# NullPointerException using Apache bzip2 library

Tags: java

I am using the BZip2 compression library from Apache Ant. The documentation is given at - 
http://javadoc.haefelinger.it/org.apache.ant/1.7.1/org/apache/tools/bzip2/CBZip2InputStream.html

I keep getting this error when I run the code -

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tools.bzip2.CBZip2InputStream.bsR(CBZip2InputStream.java:323)
    at org.apache.tools.bzip2.CBZip2InputStream.bsGetUChar(CBZip2InputStream.java:341)
    at org.apache.tools.bzip2.CBZip2InputStream.initBlock(CBZip2InputStream.java:230)
    at org.apache.tools.bzip2.CBZip2InputStream.<init>(CBZip2InputStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.tools.bzip2.bzipCompression.main(bzipCompression.java:37)
```

The error is at line -

```
**CBZip2InputStream cin = new CBZip2InputStream(fileInputStream);**
```

My source code is -

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NullPointerException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    FileReader inFile = new FileReader("alice29.txt");
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(inFile);

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("alicea.txt");
    fout.write("BZ".getBytes());


    CBZip2OutputStream czout = new CBZip2OutputStream (fout);

    String message = buff.readLine(); // read first line

    while(message!=null){
        byte[] input = message.getBytes();
        czout.write(input);
        message = buff.readLine();
    }
    czout.flush();
    czout.close();


    InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("alicea.txt");
    CBZip2InputStream cin = new CBZip2InputStream(fileInputStream);
    FileOutputStream decOut = new FileOutputStream("decompressedAlice.txt");


    byte[] buf = new byte[100000];
    int len;

    while((len = cin.read(buf))>0){
        decOut.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    decOut.close();
    cin.close();

}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What's to stop you from setting up a breakpoint on NPE (or CBZip2InputStream line 323) to see exactly which variable -- most probably a member of CBZip2InputStream -- is null? That should give you some clues instead of us guessing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are opening a FileOutputStream to alicea.txt

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("alicea.txt");
```

This OutputStream is never closed in your code, but in the error-Line you open a FileInputStream on the same file:

```
InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("alicea.txt");
CBZip2InputStream cin = new CBZip2InputStream(fileInputStream);
```

IMHO while you have an open FileOutputStream on a file, you can not open a file InputStream on the same file. That may be the reason, why your FileInputStream is NULL and the exception is thrown.

**Update:**
There is a known bug in the CBZip2InputStream and a solution described in the year 2002 (still can be found at [MarkMail](http://markmail.org/message/7w2oy4hwu744kxx2#query%3abzip2.CBZip2InputStream.bsR+page:1+mid:7w2oy4hwu744kxx2+state%3aresults)), which still exists. You have to download the java-classes and may not use a ready build .jar archive. Change the following lines in the initialize() method of CBZip2InputStream.java:

Original code (starting at line 213):

> ```
> private void initialize() {
>     char magic3, magic4;
>     magic3 = bsGetUChar();
>     magic4 = bsGetUChar();
>     if (magic3 != 'h' || magic4 < '1' || magic4 > '9') {
>         bsFinishedWithStream();
>         streamEnd = true;
>         return;
>     }
>     setDecompressStructureSizes(magic4 - '0');
>     computedCombinedCRC = 0;
> }
> ```

Change this to:

> ```
> private void initialize() {
>     char magic1, magic2; 
>     char magic3, magic4; 
>     magic1 = bsGetUChar(); 
>     magic2 = bsGetUChar(); 
>     magic3 = bsGetUChar(); 
>     magic4 = bsGetUChar(); 
>     if (magic1 != 'B' || magic2 != 'Z' | magic3 != 'h' || magic4 < '1' || magic4 > '9') {   
>         bsFinishedWithStream();
>         streamEnd = true;
>         return;
>     }
>     setDecompressStructureSizes(magic4 - '0');
>     computedCombinedCRC = 0;
> }
> ```

**Last Update:**
I just reviewed the svn of apache ant; the bug in trunk is fixed. But despite that fact, there are many, many downloads still containing this bug. I also downloaded just an old version accidently to test your problem.

Comment: @Erik: "while you have a open FileOutputStream on a file, you can not open a file InputStream on the same file" -- care to provide a reference for why this might be true?

Comment: I added fout.close(); and also changed the permissions of alicea.txt to read, write and execute.
but that did not solve the problem :(

Comment: @aix: will try to find a reference for you. But I have never ever seen this in my life. You usually open one filedescriptor to one file from a single instance and not several.

Comment: @Erik - CBZip2OutputStream will compress the file, and I do see a compressed file in my directory. The name of the compressed file is alicea.txt.

In the second step, I'm trying to decompress the file and see if the contents of the decompressed file are exactly same as the contents of the original file - alice29.txt

I think that CBZip2InputStream is supposed to decompress the file

Comment: @Ashish Agarwal it would be great from you to accept my answer as solution (click that checkmark under the counter of my answer), so others can see, that the question is answered.